# Problem on the inequality in $L^p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces, convolution, measurable-functions

The convolution off and $g$ on $\mathbb{R}^d$ equipped with Lebesgue measure is defined by $$f*g(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x-y)g(y)dy.$$
Define $||f||_{L^\infty} =$ inf$\{ M : |f(x)|< M$ for $\mu$ a.e. $x \in X\}$.

Assume $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$ and $f \in L^p, g \in L^q$. Prove $f*g \in L^\infty$ and  $||f*g||_{L^\infty} \leq ||f||_{L^p}||g||_{L^q}$.

**My fist attempt:**

Let  $|g(y)|dy = d\mu_2$. Then $||f*g||_\infty \leq || \,|f|*|g| \.||_{L^\infty} = || \int_{\mathbb{R}^d } |f(x-y)| \, |g(y)| \, dy ||_{L^\infty}$

$= || \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}  |f(x-y)| d \mu_2 ||_{L^\infty} \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} || \,|f(x-y)| \, ||_{L^\infty} d \mu_2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} || \,|f(x)| \, ||_{L^\infty} d \mu_2$

$= \| |f(x)| \|_{L^\infty}  \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}  = \| |f(x)| \|_{L^\infty}  \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |g(y)| dy = \| |f(x)| \|_{L^\infty}  \|g\|_1$

But I don't think $\| |f(x)| \|_{L^\infty}  \|g\|_1 \leq ||f||_{L^p}||g||_{L^q}$.

**My second attempt:**

So for any $\epsilon > 0$, since  $||f||_{L^\infty} - \epsilon < ||f||_{L^\infty} =$ inf$\{ M : |f(x)|< M$ for $\mu$ a.e. $x \in X\}$, it must be the case that $\{x : |f(x)| > ||f||_\infty - \epsilon\}$ has measure greater then $0$. In other words for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $\mu(\{x : |f(x)| > ||f||_\infty - \epsilon\}) > \delta$.

Let $|g(y)|dy = d\mu_2~$, we get $$||f*g||_{L^\infty} = ||\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x - y)g(y)dy||_{L^\infty} = ||\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x - y)d\mu_2|| _{L^\infty}  \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} ||f(x - y)||_{L^\infty} d\mu_2 
= \int_{\{x : |f(x)| > ||f||_{L^\infty} + \epsilon\}} ||f||_{L^\infty} d\mu_2 + \int_{\{x : |f(x)| \leq  |f||_{L^\infty} + \epsilon\}} ||f||_{L^\infty} d\mu_2~.$$

But I feel like this is not the right approach as I now have the sum of two integrals instead of the product of integrals.

**My third attempt:**

By Holdors inequality $\|f\|_{L^p}\|g\|_{L^q} \geq \|fg\|_{L_1}$

But I don't think $\|fg\|_{L_1} \geq ||f * g||_{L\infty}$.

Comment: It’s much simpler than that. Note that $| f*g(0)|\le\|f\|_p\|g\|_q$ is literally just Holders. To bound it at a point other than 0, use Holders in exactly the same way and then the translation invariance of lebesgue measure.

Comment: But wont that just give me $\|f*g\|_{L^1} \leq \|f\|_{L^p} \|g\|_{L^q}$ not $\|f*g\|_{L^\infty} \leq \|f\|_{L^p} \|g\|_{L^q}$

Comment: No, what you think it gives you has two integrals on the left Hand side which is not correct. First make sure you agree with my first point. Then Write the definition of everything out carefully

Comment: I see what your saying about not having two integrals on the left hand side, but isn't $g(0)$ just a constant so you would get $|f*g(0)| = |\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x- y)g(0)dy| \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}| f(x- y)g(0)|dy = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |f(y)g(0)|dy = \|fg(0)\|_{L^1} \leq \|f\|_{L^p}\|g(0)\|_{L^q}$

Comment: No, $f*g(x)$ has no $g(x)$. it has a $g(y)$, or alternatively a $g(x-y)$ in an integral wrt $dy$ Your answer below is correct

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be an answer

$|f*g| = |\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x - y)g(y)dy| \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |f(x- y)g(y)|dy = \|f(x - y)g(y)\|_{L^1} \leq \|f(x - y)\|_{L^p}\|g\|_{L^q} = \|f\|_{L^p}\|g\|_{L^q}$ where the fourth inequality follows from Holders inequality and the fifth inequality holds by invariants of the Lebesgue measure. Therefore $\|f\|_{L^p}\|g\|_{L^q}$ is an upper bound for $|f*g|$, for almost every $x$. So since $\|f*g\|_{L^\infty}$ is the inf $|f*g|$ for almost every $x$ we have $\|f*g\|_{L^\infty} \leq \|f\|_{L^p}\|g\|_{L^q}$

Comment: It is correct.Just one more addition,the convolution actually happens to be continuous,so you can just as well replace essential supremum with supremum itself(since the complement of a measure zero subset of $\mathbb{R}$ happens to be dense).The convolution actually introduces more regularity to our setting,it is usually atleast as regular as both $f$ and $g$.